# LayoutParams setMargins not working on API 23 and lower

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add a view programmatically and set it to a specific location on the screen.

Adding the view:

```
View view = new View(this);
```

Then I'm adding a GlobalLayoutListener

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = slidingTabLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
```

And finally in onGlobalLayout I'm setting its location:

```
public void onGlobalLayout() {

       int width = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

       int viewWidth = (int) (width * 0.18);

       int viewHeight = (int) (viewWidth / 3);

       LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(viewWidth, viewHeight);

       layoutParams.setMargins((int) (0.81 * width), (int) (slidingTabLayout.getY() + slidingTabLayout.getHeight() - (height / 2)), 0, 0);

       view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); 
}
```

*I've also tried using ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams*

Using API 24 and above this works well, but API 23 (and lower) ignores the margins and the view is placed on the top left corner of the screen.

How can this issue be solved to support all API levels?

Comment: `view.requestLayout()`?

Comment: I've tried it, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: What is "someLayout"? Is it a ConstraintLayout or something else? Also, how is `width` and `height` set? I don't think your posted your actual code, since you are dividing `view` by 2 and `view` is a _View_. It would be helpful to post more of your actual code.

Comment: Thank you for noticing, I didn't copy/paste some of the code to simplify things. I will edit the question.

Comment: Can you please provide some UI for what is expected and what is happening ? @UdiIdan

Comment: Is this happening on some specific device for on all devices? If it happens in some device then you might want to use `view.invalidate()` to redraw the view.

Comment: @UdiIdan have you for any fix so far ?

Comment: @Ravindra-RaviVerma the accepted answer is working, although it's a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve encountered a similar issue and have resolved it using different approaches for API > 23 and API <= 23.

So for API <= 23 instead of using margins I’ve used setX(float x) and setY(float y).

In your case it would be something like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    layoutParams.setMargins((int) (0.81 * width), (int) (slidingTabLayout.getY() + slidingTabLayout.getHeight() - (viewHeight / 2)), 0, 0);
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
} else {
    view.setX((int) (0.81 * width));
    view.setY((int) (slidingTabLayout.getY() + slidingTabLayout.getHeight() - (viewHeight / 2)));
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Although it doesn't solve the issue itself, it does work and gets the task done.